# Using a non-consumable in-App purchase with ID's

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, identifier

I'm using in-App purchases in my App on behave of getting some sounds from the App to the iPhone as a ringtone.

I've used 'Consumable' as the type for in-App purchase so that the user would be able to buy a ringtone and download it directly.

However this App got rejected by Apple because they want this function to be non-Consumable (so you would be able to retrieve this ringtone more than once). I only don't know how to set this up in my App because there are more than 200 possible ringtones. The actual buying is not the difficult part but as a criteria for in-App purchases you need to be able to restore previous transactions. As I'm only using one product identifier I think I would not be able to identify which ringtone has been purchases when restoring.

So my final questions: 
1. How can I identify which item is bought (i.e. by using tags in the purchase)? 
2. Am I able to use only 1 product identifier for this In-App purchase. Or do I need to make a productIdentifier for each and every ringtone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a non-Consumable product for each ringtone, each one with a different identifier, if Apple is refusing your app I think you have no other choice.

Comment: So, how will know which product is bought? How to I assign, say, an image to a particular product identifier? Thank you!

Comment: take a look to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial), I think this is exactly what you are looking for